# Issue with Regex Extract Integer

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract the number within the parenthesis.

Ex: `String a = Value-Match  (70%)`

My regex pattern: `Value-Match\w+\((\d+)\)`

I would like to extract 70 if the string Value-Match matched.

Comment: You can try [`Value-Match\s*\(.*?(\d+).*?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZHCiDM/1)

Comment: Replace `\w` with `\W`